# How to implement the style of Quill html output when rendering it in another app?

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I'm using quill editor on our B2B and the user can customize his text, and I get back a HTML format of the text.

But when I'm displaying the HTML on the B2C side I don't have the quill editor installed and I don't get all custom style,
is there any different solution except installing quill editor ?
my HTML looks like this:
`[innerHtml]="<some HTML from quill editor>`

I get the HTML with quill custom class

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ5od.png)

[I'm expecting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYsXd.png)

[But getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LO99.png)

Comment: It is not possible without adding at least the styles of quill - see my answer below. Next time, consider to use Object format instead of html format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to include the link to `quill`'s stylesheet in your `index.html`, as described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill#download).

Then, you have to wrap your html element where you put the quill html ouput, with an additional `<div>` with the following clases as described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill#:%7E:text=QuillViewHTMLComponent%20%2D%20Using%20angular%20%5BinnerHTML%5D):

```
<div class="ql-container ql-snow" style="border-width: 0;">
  <div class="ql-editor" [innerHTML]="byPassedHTMLString">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you are good to go. Recompile your app and see the magic in action!